# Blockchain Imported Address

Tags: blockchain.info, importaddress

I have created a blockchain wallet after l loaded it the next day the balance was zero but l have realized there is an imported address which l didn't import. Is there any way l can recover the funds back. l can see all the transactions of the imported address.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way l can recover the funds

No.

### No key No bitcoin

To recover control over funds associated with an address, you need the seed-phrase (AKA recovery phrase) or private-keys.

An address imported into a wallet allows you to see money belonging to someone else (or to another wallet of yours, perhaps an offline wallet). It does not give you control over that money and there is no way to get control if you only have the address.

### Custodial wallets

Some wallets are called custodial wallets (though not by the wallet providers) and are more like an account with a business that looks after your money for you and issues you with a kind of IOU. The business is the actual owner of the money. For this kind of wallet you should contact the money owner (the business).

Some businesses of this sort offer both custodial wallets and normal non-custodial wallets. Blockchain.com might be one of these. In that case what to do next depends a lot on exactly what sort of wallet you have.

### Scams

Imported addresses are a favourite trick of scammers. If someone else helped you create your wallet, you may have been a victim.